# remove the error in html5 canvas

Tags: html

I'm just trying to create a canvas in my browser  with the following code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng">
<head>
<title<abc</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=canvasApp();

function canvasApp()
{
var canvas=document.getElementById("one");
if(!canvas||!canvas.getContext)
    return;
}

</script>



<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<canvas id="one" width="400" height="500"> 
Your browser doesn't support canvas
</canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Why i'm getting canvas=null in the following line

`var canvas=document.getElementById("one");`

(I'm using the latest versions of chrome and firefox)

Comment: Try flipping that `<title<` tag's closing angled bracket around.

Comment: Also: `window.onload=canvasApp;`

Comment: Also: You forgot the `</head>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML leaves somewhat to be desired.

Give the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) a go. Right now it reports 7 Errors and 4 warnings.

Comment: Sorry guys,my code had some serious typos.
The indication by @leppie mere solved the issue.
Also i typed <title< ,forgot </head>,etc. in the excitement.

Thnx all for your advice and help